# Issues with authorization on Microsoft Office using OAuth 2.0 on PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, phpmailer

I'm having some issues with OAuth 2.0 authorization during SMTP mail sending via PHPMail.

Basically, I've tried all of the below listed scopes:

- `email`
- `openid`
- `profile`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`
- `User.Read`
- `SMTP.Send`
- `Mail.Send`
- `offline_access`

With the following Auth URIs:

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`

With the following hostnames:

- `smtp.office365.com`
- `smtp.outlook.com`

And nothing works. :(

Here is the verbose output of PHPMailer:

```
2022-09-06 14:55:41 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-09-06 14:55:41 Connection: opened
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "220 BLAPR03CA0009.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 6 Sep 2022 14:55:40 +0000"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 BLAPR03CA0009.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 6 Sep 2022 14:55:40 +0000
2022-09-06 14:55:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO <REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY_REASONS>.org
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BLAPR03CA0009.outlook.office365.com Hello [150.136.30.43]"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-BLAPR03CA0009.outlook.office365.com Hello [150.136.30.43]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-09-06 14:55:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2022-09-06 14:55:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO <REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY_REASONS>.org
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BLAPR03CA0009.outlook.office365.com Hello [150.136.30.43]"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2022-09-06 14:55:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-BLAPR03CA0009.outlook.office365.com Hello [150.136.30.43]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-09-06 14:55:41 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
2022-09-06 14:55:41 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,XOAUTH2
2022-09-06 14:55:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 <TOKEN REMOVED FOR SECURITY REASONS>
2022-09-06 14:55:47 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BLAPR03CA0009.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]"
2022-09-06 14:55:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BLAPR03CA0009.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]
2022-09-06 14:55:47 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BLAPR03CA0009.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2022-09-06 14:55:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-09-06 14:55:47 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2022-09-06 14:55:47 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2022-09-06 14:55:47 Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

And here is the `var_dump` of the Access Token variable handled by Steven Maguire's Provider:

```
object(League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken)#33 (5) {

  ["accessToken":protected]=>

  string(2012) "<TOKEN REMOVED FOR SECURITY REASONS>"

  ["expires":protected]=>

  int(1662481291)

  ["refreshToken":protected]=>

  string(848) "<TOKEN REMOVED FOR SECURITY REASONS>"

  ["resourceOwnerId":protected]=>

  NULL

  ["values":protected]=>

  array(3) {

    ["token_type"]=>

    string(6) "Bearer"

    ["scope"]=>

    string(134) "email openid profile https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"

    ["ext_expires_in"]=>

    int(5150)

  }

}
```

The funny thing is that PHPMailer's internal code suggests using `wl.offline_access` and `wl.imap`, as well as most of the how-tos suggesting `wl.basic` and `wl.emails`. Those kinds of scopes are **deprecated**.

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Unfortunately my experience with OAuth flows is that they are nearly always painful. You may be better off setting up an app password, which allows you to skip OAuth altogether.  Anything deprecated is probably because that hasn't been looked at from the PHPMailer direction for a long time – I don't keep track of what MS changes. PRs welcome!

Comment: @Synchro Could you refer me to the app password setup guide? I am not really sure what is that, because no guide has referenced that :P

Comment: Try searching for it? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944

Comment: @Synchro Unfortunately, this method won't help, because Microsoft is sunsetting the Basic Auth all together in October. Even with custom app passwords.

Comment: That was news to me, and I found a a good reference for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online