# Getting "invalid_client" when using obtained oauth token (Microsoft) with phpmailer

Tags: outlook, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, office365, phpmailer

Can't seem to get this working. Any idea why?

This is my MS configuration:

[authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSk57.png)

[api/permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nWyx.jpg)

[token configuration (empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar3TA.png)

["expose an api" (empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR8yg.png)

Code obtaining token (works fine):

```
new \Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft([
    'clientId'                  => "my_id...",
    'clientSecret'              => "my_secret...",
    'redirectUri'               => "https://example.com/get/get_oauth_token.php",
    'accessType'                => 'offline',
    // Optional (what is this doing??)
    'urlAuthorize'              => 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'            => 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails'   => 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me'
    ]);
$authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl([
    'scope' => ['wl.basic', 'wl.signin', 'wl.emails'] // no idea what I need here and what not - does it have to align with the app permissions?
]);
$_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
```

Using token to send mail:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Timeout = 10;
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com"; // smtp.office365.com, outlook.office.com, smtp-mail.outlook.com which one is it even?? Doesnt make a difference
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

// (omitting all mail content stuff here)

$provider = new \Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft([
    'clientId'                  => "my_id...",
    'clientSecret'              => "my_secret...",
    'redirectUri'               => "https://example.com/get/get_oauth_token.php" // is this necessary here?
]);

//Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth([
        'provider' => $provider,
        'clientId' => "my_id...",
        'clientSecret' => "my_secret...",
        'refreshToken' => "my_refreshToken...",
        // 'oauthToken' => $token, // ? are we completely ignoring the actual access token in all of this? do we ever need to update our refresh token?
        'userName' => 'me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com' // supposed to be user that gave consent? 
    ])
);

$mail->send();
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

Getting this error:

```
2022-09-22 17:49:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 FR0P281CA0070.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 22 Sep 2022 17:49:07 +0000

2022-09-22 17:49:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com

2022-09-22 17:49:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-FR0P281CA0070.outlook.office365.com Hello [85.13.129.169]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8

2022-09-22 17:49:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2022-09-22 17:49:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

2022-09-22 17:49:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com

2022-09-22 17:49:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-FR0P281CA0070.outlook.office365.com Hello [85.13.129.169]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8

Bad Request
/www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft/src/Provider/Microsoft.php(79)
    #0 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(628): Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft->checkResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
    #1 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(537): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
    #2 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php(115): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getAccessToken(Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\RefreshToken), Array)
    #3 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php(128): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth->getToken()
    #4 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php(598): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth->getOauth64()
    #5 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(2190): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP->authenticate('', '', 'XOAUTH2', Object(PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth))
    #6 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(2003): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
    #7 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1662): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 22 S...', 'test content\r\n')
    #8 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1500): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()
    #9 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/includes/helpers/mail.php(182): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
    #10 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/includes/helpers/mail.php(113): mailSendSingle(Object(PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer), Array, true)
    #11 /www/htdocs/w014af32/me/get/test4.php(25): mailSend(Array)
    #12 {main}
    # Args: 
        checkResponse: [{},{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https:\/\/go.microsoft.com\/fwlink\/?linkid=2083908.","correlation_id":"4dc377bd-0d5d-4444-bdd4-82b862f86177"}]
        getParsedResponse: [{}]
        getAccessToken: [{},{"refresh_token":"my refreshToken..."}]
        authenticate: ["","","XOAUTH2",{}]
        smtpConnect: [{"ssl":{"verify_peer":false,"verify_peer_name":false,"allow_self_signed":true}}]
        smtpSend: ["Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 19:49:08 +0200\r\nTo: John Doe <me@example.com>\r\nFrom: John Doe <me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com>\r\nReply-To: John Doe <me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com>\r\nSubject: test mail\r\nMessage-ID: <AAtH5DrcPQ9Fn4PysOdjIt0OnDbByC4eaRYVnJh33M@example.com>\r\nX-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.4 (https:\/\/github.com\/PHPMailer\/PHPMailer)\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text\/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n","test content\r\n"]
        mailSendSingle: [{"Priority":null,"CharSet":"utf-8","ContentType":"text\/html","Encoding":"7bit","ErrorInfo":"","From":"me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com","FromName":"John Doe","Sender":"me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com","Subject":"test mail","Body":"test content","AltBody":"","Ical":"","WordWrap":0,"Mailer":"smtp","Sendmail":"\/usr\/sbin\/sendmail","UseSendmailOptions":true,"ConfirmReadingTo":"","Hostname":"","MessageID":"","MessageDate":"","Host":"smtp.office365.com","Port":"587","Helo":"","SMTPSecure":"tls","SMTPAutoTLS":true,"SMTPAuth":true,"SMTPOptions":{"ssl":{"verify_peer":false,"verify_peer_name":false,"allow_self_signed":true}},"Username":"","Password":"","AuthType":"XOAUTH2","Timeout":10,"dsn":"","SMTPDebug":2,"Debugoutput":"html","SMTPKeepAlive":false,"SingleTo":false,"do_verp":false,"AllowEmpty":false,"DKIM_selector":"","DKIM_identity":"","DKIM_passphrase":"","DKIM_domain":"","DKIM_copyHeaderFields":true,"DKIM_extraHeaders":[],"DKIM_private":"","DKIM_private_string":"","action_function":"","XMailer":""},{"from_mail":"me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com","from_name":"John Doe","smtp_profile":3,"from_user":1,"to_mail":"me@example.com","to_name":"John Doe","to_type":"staff","to_id":3,"template":0,"debug":true,"testing":true,"subject":"test mail","type":"test","date":"2022-09-22 19:49:08","content":"test content","reply_to":"me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com"},true]
        mailSend: [{"from_mail":"me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com","from_name":"John Doe","smtp_profile":3,"from_user":1,"to_mail":"me@example.com","to_name":"John Doe","to_type":"staff","to_id":3,"template":0,"debug":true,"testing":true,"subject":"test mail","type":"test","date":"2022-09-22 19:49:08","content":"test content","reply_to":"me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com"}]
2022-09-22 17:49:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2022-09-22 17:49:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

I know it's a lot of code but there isn't really much to say, I could ommit the whole token obtaining because it works. I assume the error lies somewhere in the azure configuration? The user I've obtained the token with is just a "member" (Role "Global administrator"), the "owner" of the app is another one.

Comment: Are you trying to send email using a personal account (e.g. outlook.com, hotmail.com, etc.)? Or using a work or school account (e.g. Azure AD/Microsoft 365/Azure) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using these options for the provider (in both places, aquiring token and sending mail) did it (it's the tenant id):

```
'urlAuthorize' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/b3095h58-5987-4489-a1dd-b132f2f38113/oauth2/authorize',
'urlAccessToken' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/b3095h58-5987-4489-a1dd-b132f2f38113/oauth2/token'
```

It seemed irrelevant whether to use windows.net or microsoftonline.com

However now I'm at the same point as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624313/issues-with-authorization-on-microsoft-office-using-oauth-2-0-on-phpmailer). Funnily even using Thunderbird to test the oauth authentification fails for sending (receiving is fine though).