# Connection refused to outlook.company.com mail server through php

Tags: php, symfony, phpmailer

Question,
i am using symfony mailer for 6.1 (https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html)  and i seem to be getting a connection refused when trying to send an email to the server. Normally, i would assume username / password but i'm 99% sure it's sending the correct credentials to the server. When i dump the contents of the mailer object i can see the -username -password objects which match to what they should be.

Using the following settings, port 587, smtp, outlook.company_name.com, Authmode login (Tried with and without in the DSN string), I Tried enabling TLS and disabling it on the same port 587. I Was wondering if anyone has some good example(S) on getting this to work properly? I have verified the username / password as it lets me in via the web gui, but i have a feeling it's something special i'm probably doing with either the DSN string or some other setting/incorrect port maybe. I'm also not sure what the correct way to debug this would be if anyone has any tips.

Comment: It would be more useful if you posted the actual DSN instead of describing it. Keep in mind that if your user / passsword has any special character, it has to be `urlencoded`. That said, since the error is "connection refused" and not an authentication failure, I'd say it's a dns or the server's smtp connection misconfiguration. Get in touch with your infrastructure team if you can.

Comment: So it has the urlencoded values in the dsn, And it can reach the server. 
smtps://username:password@outlook.company.com:587?&auth_mode=login

I also tried hard coding the ip of the server. At this point, Not 100% sure if it's an issue with auto discovery of the settings it needs, or it's legitimately blocked. As with the same settings it seems to work fine with a python module we setup.

Answer (score 0):

If your Outlook service is hosted by Microsoft, it's very likely that you're seeing [their policy change that no longer allows SMTP authentication using ID and password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online).

You need to implement XOAUTH2 support, which although technically supported by PHPMailer (which you're not actually using as it's not the same thing as Symphony mailer), is proving [very difficult to get working in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624313/issues-with-authorization-on-microsoft-office-using-oauth-2-0-on-phpmailer?noredirect=1#comment130165244_73624313).

Comment: Yea we got it working correctly using a python module exchangelib, i've been trying to figure out why one works (with bare miminum settings) and php is just being horrible today. i'm pretty sure ours is internally hosted though, but not 100%

Answer (score 0):

@rob Take a look at my new wiki article and see if this helps you set it up

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-and-XOAUTH2-setup-guide